# how to insert bulk data using PLSQL in mysql with dynamic value

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql

I need to insert dynamic values to a table and insert some data to its child tables also. Tables contains some unique field also. For unique field, it should be inserted as temp1, temp2, temp3...., I will be thankful if somebody shows a sample code to insert 100 records dynamically to the parent and its child table as I am new to the PLSQL.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge MySQL does not support PLSQL, which (again, to the best of my knowledge) is only supported by Oracle and IBM's DB2 database products. Best of luck.

Comment: I created a small java file that connects to the database and inserted 10 million records.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this as PLSQL isn't support by MySQL. [plsql](/questions/tagged/plsql) is a [language for Oracle database handling](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/plsql/index.html).

> PL/SQL is a procedural language designed specifically to embrace SQL statements within its syntax. PL/SQL program units are compiled by the Oracle Database server and are stored inside the database. And at run-time, both PL/SQL and SQL run within the same server process, bringing optimal efficiency. PL/SQL automatically inherits the robustness, security, and portability of the Oracle Database.

What you could do is use either [php](/questions/tagged/php), [java](/questions/tagged/java) or any other programming language to do your inserts.